# Ternary sequence of length $n$ with no pairs

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> What is the number of ternary sequences of length $n$ over $\{0,1,2\}$ with no pairs ?

So i define $a_n$ as the general sequence - and let $b_n - a_n$ sequence that end in a $0,$
$c_n - a_n$ sequence that end in a $1,$
$d_n - a_n$ sequence that end in a $2.$

Obviously - $a_n = b_n +c_n +d_n$.
Also - we can say that the $b_n$ for one, because it defined the number of $a_n$ sequences that end in a $0$ it is actually combined of $bn = c_{n-1} + d_{n-1}$.

Same goes for $c_n, d_n$, and after all we have $a_n = b_n +c_n +d_n =  2b_{n-1} + 2c_{n-1} + 2d_{n-1} = 2a_{n-1}.$

Therefore - the characteristic polynomial is $A\cdot2_n$ (for $A\in\Bbb{R}$) and we can say that $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 3 a_2 = 6.$, Which is not fulfilled for any $A$.

What have i done wrong ? thank you !

Comment: What is meant by a "pair"?

Comment: no $00, 11, 22$.

Comment: your reasoning is correct, but can only be applied for $n>1$. So this gives $a_n=3\cdot 2^{n-1}$ for $n\ge 1$.